# stateless API DB connection pattern

Tags: c#, database, api, rest

I am writing a (C#) stateless Rest api that returns data from a MS SQL server. It replaces a curently existing JAVA API that uses a lot of hardcoded queries to access the data. 
Inside the api I'm building I'll need to have the controllers be able to target multiple databases. There is no session management not are there any authentication issues

What is a good approach for handling data access? 
one option is to create all the connection objects for each request. I worry that this would cause quite some overhead. Another option is to use a singleton for each database connection.

Any advice on this matter is welcome

Comment: Dpendency injection. And let the application handle it. A singleton might force you to activate MARS

Comment: MARS? @ThomasAndreèLian

Comment: @ThomasAndreèLian use DI and recreate all required objects for each call?

Comment: with DI you can control how you create the DbInstance and pass it to the controllers (instead of working with singletons). In any case if you don't create a new connection per API call of perform work on the DB Context by multiple threads at the same time you might run into a message along the lines "this connection is in use" thus you must turn on MARS "Multiple Active Result Sets"